# np.random.choice conflict with multiprocessing? multiprocessing inside for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, numpy-random

I want to use **np.random.choice** inside a **multiprocessing pool**, but I get the **IndexError: list index out of range**. I don't get any error when I use the choice function inside a for loop (in series then, not parallel). Any ideas on how to overcome this? This is just a small part of my routine but would surely improve a lot its speed. My code is like below. I declare X before anything else in the routine so it works as a global variable, but it's dynamically populated inside the **main**. I also noticed that there is some conflict with **multiprocessing** and the **for loop**. Any ideas on how to implement this?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from numpy.random import choice
import numpy as np

K = 10
X = []

def function(k):
   
   global X
   np.random.RandomState(k)

   aux = [i for i in np.arange(K) if i != k]
   a,b,c = choice(aux,3,replace=False)
   x = X[a]+0.7*(X[b]-X[c])
   return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    X = np.arange(K)

    for n in range(K):
    
        pool = Pool(K)
        w = pool.map(function,np.arange(K))
        pool.close()
    
        print(w)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child processes do not share the memory space of parent processes. Since you populate `X` inside the `if __name__ ...` clause, the child processes only have access to the X defined at the top module, i.e `X = []`

A quick solution would be to shift the line `X = np.arange(K)` outside the clause like below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from numpy.random import choice
import numpy as np

K = 10
X = []
X = np.arange(K)


def function(k):
    global X
    np.random.RandomState(k)

    aux = [i for i in np.arange(K) if i != k]
    a, b, c = choice(aux, 3, replace=False)
    x = X[a] + 0.7 * (X[b] - X[c])
    return k, x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(10)
    w = pool.map(function, np.arange(K))
    pool.close()

    print(w)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 10.899999999999999), (1, 9.4), (2, 5.7), (3, 7.4), (4, 1.1000000000000005), (5, -1.0999999999999996), (6, 5.6), (7, 3.8), (8, 5.5), (9, -4.8999999999999995)]
```

If you do not want to initialize `X` for all child processes (memory constraints?), you can use a [manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to store `X` that can be shared to processes without having to copy it for every child. To pass more than one argument to the child processes, you will also have to use [pool.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead. Lastly, delete that `global X`, it is not doing anything useful since `global` is only used if you are planning to modify a global variable from a local scope.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from numpy.random import choice
import numpy as np

K = 10


def function(X, k):

    np.random.RandomState(k)

    aux = [i for i in np.arange(K) if i != k]
    a, b, c = choice(aux, 3, replace=False)
    x = X[a] + 0.7 * (X[b] - X[c])
    return k, x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    X = m.list(np.arange(K))

    pool = Pool(10)
    args = [(X, val) for val in np.arange(K)]

    w = pool.starmap(function, args)
    pool.close()

    print(w)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, -1.5999999999999996), (1, 7.3), (2, 4.9), (3, 1.9000000000000004), (4, 5.5), (5, -1.0999999999999996), (6, 4.800000000000001), (7, 7.3), (8, 0.10000000000000053), (9, 4.7)]
```

Comment: hi @Charchit, thanks for your response. Sorry it took me so long to get back to this. I tested what you proposed and it worked, but then I tried to create multiprocessing pools inside a for loop (I should execute the same parallel evaluations for a number of times) and I get really strange errors. Any ideas on this? I updated my question.

Comment: I just found out that I shouldn't start the pool every iteration of the for loop. Now it works superbly. Thanks again.